# Should a new app be created to handle syndication of a blog?

Tags: django, frameworks, syndication

The blog is simple.  I just make posts with text and pictures.  That being the case, I'm wondering if it is best to put my Feed class in the models.py of my blog app, or create a new app specifically for the Feed class.

Comment: A seperate app for RSS may be overkill but it certainly is good practice and you might save yourself some time when you need a RSS app for your next Django project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Django syndication framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/), I would not bother creating a separate app.

Your feed class is going to be coupled to your blog model anyway, so I don't see the advantage of putting it in a separate app.

```
class LatestEntriesFeed(Feed):
    ...
    def items(self):
        return MyBlogEntry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Comment: Thanks Alsadir and namsral.  I'm going to put it in my blog model.  Makes more sense to do it that way.